# Cypress: Log-in for one test and stay logged-in for the next test

Tags: cypress

I would like to know if there is a way to log in within one `it()` and be able to stay logged in for the next `it()`

As an example:

```
it('logs in', () =>{
    cy.login('username', 'password');// This calls a custom command
})

it('next step', () =>{
    cy.get('div.nextStep').click();
})
```

I know I can use `before()` to log in and then `beforeEach()` and capture the cookie, and this way, the session persists, but I want to log in inside an `it()` and the user stays logged in for the test in the next `it()`, is this possible?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: It will log in, but when it leaves the first it(), and goes into the second the user will be logged out

Comment: This sort of testing structure is considered an anti-pattern, as tests should not be dependent on other tests for their data and setup. I would strongly encourage you to use a before/beforeEach block to log in.

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using? The behavior for accomplishing this changed dramatically between 9.7.0 and 10+

Comment: Hi. Would be really helpful if you could share that `login` custom command. How the login is performed there? Do you set your authentication session ('token') in any of browser storages, or you just simulate some UI actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do that in Cypress 12, turn off testIsolation.

[Test Isolation Disabled](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation#Test-Isolation-Disabled)

> When test isolation is disabled, Cypress will not alter the browser context before the test starts. The page does not clear between tests and **cookies, local storage and session storage will be available across tests** in that suite. Additionally, the `cy.session()` command will only clear the current browser context when establishing the browser session - the current page is not cleared.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    testIsolation: false,
  },
})
```

I've highlighted the part that is important for `cy.login()`. Keeping the artifacts of the login process will enable the second test to pass.

Answer (score 0):

**Cypress 13** has **[session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) handling**. So you don't need these workarounds from above anymore.

an example:

```
cy.session(
    [user, password],
    () => {
        cy.visit('/auth/login');

        type('#user_name', user);
        type('#user_password', password);

        cy.get('#user_login_submit').click();
        cy.url().should('contain', '/main');
    },
    {
        cacheAcrossSpecs: true,
    },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach:

If you used it beforeEach() and afterEach() this will persists the browser session for every it() block.

Please add the custom command in /support/command.js

```
let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

Cypress.Commands.add("saveLocalStorageCache", () => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("restoreLocalStorageCache", () => {
  Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
  });
});
```

And add this code in /support/index.js

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorageCache();
})
afterEach(() => {
  cy.saveLocalStorageCache();
})
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.